# Listing Object names from GCS bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In one of my requirement need to list object names from GCS bucket i am following correct method .please check my code snippet.i have added all required OAuth jars .

```
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
            Credential credential;
            try {
                credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(httpTransport)                    
                        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                        .setServiceAccountId(
                                "")
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                                new File(
                                        "WEB-INF/key.p12")).build();                    
                Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                        credential).setApplicationName("span-test-app").setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<StorageObject> objects = storage.objects().list("spanbigdata")
                        .execute().getItems();
                if (objects != null) {
                    for (StorageObject o : objects) {
                        out.println(o.getName());
                    }
```

Error 
No such method error .
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountScopes(Ljava/util/Collection;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential$Builder;

if i remove setscopesmethod . it is giving Null pointer exception . please help me fixing this issue.

Comment: What is the content of the NPE? What is null and does the stack trace point at a specific culprit line?